# Substitutions in Integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have the integral $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ and I wish to make a substitution $x=g(u)$. On making this substitution, I evaluate the integral $\int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)} f(g(u) ) g'(u) du$ not in the Cartesian $x$-$y$ plane but in the Cartesian $u$-$ f(g(u) ) g'(u) $ plane. We assume that the mapping $g: u \rightarrow x$ be one-to-one. I am finding it quite hard to find a reason behind this assumption. If the mapping were not one-to-one, what could happen while evaluating the integral?

An example will also help me understand.

Comment: Look at the example: $\int_0^\pi f(x)dx$ take $g(u)=\cos(u)$, what happens to the integral?

Comment: @Holo, there exists no real $u$ for which I can evaluate $g^{-1}(\pi)$.

Comment: sorry, I meant let $g{-1}=\sin$. This will give you contradiction.

Comment: @Holo, I see that the integral evaluates to 0 irrespective of what the new integrand is. I think I got it. If I take $f(x)= \sin(x)$ in your example, $\sin(x) =u$ is not a valid transformation. It is also not one-one along the $u$ axis.

Comment: It is not valid because $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x) dx \neq 0$.

Comment: yes, exactly,..

Answer (score 0):

Forget about $g^{-1}$ The theorem says if a=g(c) and b=g(d)  ,g with a continuous derivative , then

$\int_a^bf(x)dx =\int_c^df(g(u))g'(u)du$ . No use of one- one for g is needed .Of course given a and b ,you have to guess c and d . the proof is just by considering d  as a variable and checking using the chain rule that both sides have the same derivative with respect to d .and agree at d=c .

Comment: I guess I see it. Please bare with me for a moment. When $u$ and $x=g(u)$ share a one-one relation, $g^{-1}$ can be formulated. In this case, the integral can be evaluated by working with $\int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)} f(g(u) ) g'(u) du$( am I right? ). Now, what you are saying is, $u$ and $g(u)$ need not share a one-one relation. When they do not, $g^{-1}$ cannot be formulated. Is this why you discussed about guessing $c$ and $d$?

Comment: Yes exactly . Usually you are given a and b so it is necessary so determine c and d to use the formula . But you substitute g(c) for a and g(d) for b ,you get the formula without any mention of a and b ,and this is the formula that I hinted  the proof for ,and that you actually use . And of course you are right,if you know the function is one -one your original formulation is also correct . And you had good reason not to see intuitively the reason for the assumption about the inverse because it is not needed. Good question